# Can I use mtb rigid fork in touring frame?

Tags: frames, fork, bike-fit, touring

I am looking to change my fork because of some issue(broken). My problem is my headtube is the standard ec34, which is why I can't use tapered fork. So, I am looking at some mtb rigid fork, which have straight steer tube, but I am not sure whether it will work, and the sizing. A 29er fork has axle to crown distance about 430mm, but as far as I measure my former fork the axle to crown distance is only around 375-380mm. A 40mm difference, and it doesn't include the crown to steer tube distance.

Comment: Would you ride with 23mm tire in the back and 63mm tire in the front? If not, then you probably don't want to increase axle-to-crown distance by 40mm.

Comment: If you are using disc brake, you could try a fork meant for 26'' which probably has the correct axle-crown distance

Comment: Why not use an actual touring bike fork?

Comment: @RLH presumably much more expensive

Comment: @joek The OP mentions needing a straight tube steerer as their motivation for looking at a mountain bike fork, not cost. Several brands, e.g., Surly, offer straight-tube touring forks.

Comment: @RLH yeah my option are limited, i could get surly ms fork but it hard to come by, even this mtb fork i had to source from china.

Comment: @JoeK i use disc brake, the 26er has axle-to-crown distance around 370mm, bit smaller than my previous but the crown still has 40mm difference. The head angle will decreased, not sure about how it behave.

Comment: I would expect more that a dozen suitable straight tube forks are available in the qbp catalog available at most LBSs

Comment: Also, specifying your frame and your "some issue" with the fork will help yield better answers

Comment: @whatsisname well, my fork is broken, so I need to replace it

Comment: @gamalan the axle-crown measurement is generally taken from the ledge the bearing race sits on (crown race) down to the axle. The design of the fork can affect tyre clearance but doesn't change the measurement.

Comment: @JoeK thanks for the input, and explanation. will consider more.